# what path does a packet traverse on it's way out and back under multicast with loopback enabled?

Tags: networking, network-programming, multicast, latency

I am wondering if the outbound packet for loopback can be used to isolate and measure the latency of the hardware network interface card..or if this approach wouldn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably doesn't go anywhere near the NIC, just a short-circuit within the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The packet over the loopback, the packet goes down in the network stack to the loopback driver. It will not go any were near the hardware interface.